# Global logout through oracle identity federation

Tags: session, cookies, saml, federation

In achieving SSO through Oracle Identity Federation,  Identity provider will generate OAM session cookies and also federation based cookies and send SAML Assertion response  to Service provider.
Next when we Logout at service provider , only OAM session cookies are being killed but Oracle Identity Federation cookies are not being killed? 
To achieve Global logout feature, federation based cookies should also be killed at service provider but they aren't been killed.
How to kill federation based cookies at Service Provider?

Comment: Did you try anything?